# In Star Wars ep4-6, what non-human characters spoke Basic (English)?

Tags: star-wars

In the classic trilogy, what alien / non-human species spoke Basic?  I can think of Admiral Akbar -- anyone else?  Droids don't count.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Star Wars: A New Hope

- **None.** Only Humans and 'droids appear to speak English/Basic

### Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back

- **Yoda**

### Star Wars: Return of the Jedi

- **Admiral Ackbar** ("*It's a Trap!*")

- **Captain [Verrack](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Verrack)** ("*We have enemy ships in Sector 47*")

- **Random Gungan #7675** (Shouts "*we'sa'free!*" at the end of the film - Note, this is [**not Jar Jar**](http://www.killermovies.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-361361-jar-jar-binks-is-in-return-of-the-jedi.html))

Comment: it's okay, you made up for it with the Gungan.  There are other Mon Calamarians that speak on the main cruiser

Comment: There's a Gungan in RotJ?  Like, real RotJ, or post-Lucas-craziness RotJ?

Comment: @Joe - That would be "post-Lucas-craziness RotJ", I'm afraid.

Comment: oh yeah, Yoda -- durp!

Comment: @Richard Thanks.  I have wiped most of that from my memory, fortunately.

Comment: None in A New Hope?  What about the "He doesn't like you.  I don't like you either" guy in the cantina that gets his hand cut off by Obi-Wan?

Comment: @MartianInvader - The pig-faced alien in the bar is Cornelius Evazan. He's [human](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cornelius_Evazan).

Comment: @Richard Wow, I just assumed from his face he was alien.  I learned something today.

Comment: Your last video on the random Gungan gives me "This video contains content from SME. It is restricted from playback on certain sites." It works if I follow the link to YouTube.

Comment: @isanae - Is the new link better?

Comment: @isanae /cough hola plugin

Comment: @Richard [Uh, no](http://adios-hola.org/).

Answer (score 5):

You can hear an Ewok say "that guy's wise" in Return of the Jedi :D

Comment: Funny, but not really an answer to the question.

Comment: @Richard he is speaking Basic is he not? That's the question right?

Comment: He is not speaking English. He's speaking Ewok that sounds a bit like something in English. The fact that the next line is allegedly "Ooh, Martin Short" is a bit of a giveaway.

Comment: @Richard ha - I had never noticed the Martin Short thing until seeing the text in that video but I'm keeping the answer because the first Ewok clearly says 'that guys wise' - especially considering the context

Comment: I always heard it as "oh, that's wise" followed by "to be sure"

Answer (score 4):

If I heard Episode 6 right, Bib Fortuna said "he's no Jedi" and possibly "master bargain", and Jabba said a couple loanwords too.

Comment: Now we need a bunch of Expanded Universe buffs to tell us whether those are Basic loanwords in Huttese, or Huttese loanwords in Basic :D

Answer (score 2):

Yoda is the first one that comes to mind.  You also hear the singer in Jabba's palace, Sy Snootles,  say "Uh-oh" in return of the jedi, but she sings in another language.

Comment: beat me to Yoda! I always assumed the bartender was human with a deformity

Comment: @NathanK.Campbell either he was really ugly, or an alien.

Comment: The pig-faced alien in the bar is Cornelius Evazan. He's [human](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cornelius_Evazan)

Comment: @Richard removed Cornelius

Comment: @CBredlow - I believe the singer in Jabba's palace is named Sy Snootles fwiw - definitely an alien

Comment: I don't think that "uh-oh" counts, though. It's probably not exclusive to Basic, or to English in the real world.