# In Star Wars ep1-3, what non-human characters spoke Basic (English)?

Tags: star-wars, languages

As a followup to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109488), what non-human, non-droid characters in the prequel trilogy spoke Basic?  It seems like significantly more, but I have not watched these prequels more than twice...

Comment: this one might be to broad/listy.

Comment: Wow, loads. I'll leave this to others and pick holes later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Episode I**

Gungans

Neimoidians

Watto (Toydarian)

Fodesinbeed Annodue, the Troig pod racer announcer (though only his left head)

Yoda

Ki-Adi Mundi (Jedi)

Darth Maul

**Episode II**

Jetster Dexter (diner owner)

Lama Sul (the cloning scientist)

Yoda

**Episode III**:

Neimoidians

General Grievous (droid or no? - used to be an alien at least)

Comment: Episode 2: Zam (female bounty hunter), Techno Union guy, the banking clan guy, the death sticks dude, the chase scene there's an alien with a beak yelling "what the!", various younglings greet obi-wan (I think they were the bear clan or something like that)

Comment: @CDBredlow - kick those in as answers!

Comment: C3PO... Definitely not human.

Answer (score 2):

**Episode 1:**

The Chagrian who is the Chancellors Aide.

**Episode 2:**

Zam, the bounty hunter who attacks Padme

Kaminoans

There are a few non-human younglings in the Jedi temple who greet obi-wan

The man selling death sticks in the bar

Nute Gunray, Minister of trade for the Trade Federation

Wat Tambor, the Foreman of the Techno Union

**Episode 3**
The Pau'ans (of the planet Utapau)